# How does django db index work with minus?

Tags: django, database, orm

What does this index with minus (`-text`) mean in Django?

```
migrations.AddIndex(
  model_name='comment',
  index=models.Index(fields=['-text'], name='xxx'),
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Indexes are generally created in ascending order based on the named column. However, in this case, the '-' says that the index should be based on the named column in *descending* order, (or reverse alphabetical assuming text is a CharField of some sort).

The process of indexing itself tells the database that this is an important column, and that it should be pre-prepared. This means that searches on an indexed column don't have to search every row, and so are faster.

Indexing a field should speed any given database call that searches that field. Reverse indexing with the minus is useful if, for example, you know most of your searches will be for recent data, so you create a reverse index on a datetime field. On a text search, it depends if you think searches on ZYX will be more frequent than ABC - possible but very case specific.

In terms of django, you wouldn't index one column before a search in a view (for example). Instead, you might recognise that a column was used frequently in your searches, or contains a lot of data or records, or was part of very common equations (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/indexes/ for examples), so you index it at the database level, and by indexing the column you make all searches using it faster and more efficient.

Comment: Does it speedup `~Q(text='some')` better then `Index(fields=['text'])`?

Comment: I've updated my answer with some more info for you.